# Display values from relation table in xtragrid

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am having a problem with displaying values from relation table. For example I have table: Person and there I have columns like `id`, `pet_id`, `name`. Another table is Dog with `id` and `name`.

I would like to list all Persons with columns `id`, `pet_id` and `name`. But I like to have `name` of the dog in cell for column `pet_id` instead of `id` to Pet table. I created relation `Person_Dog_Relation` and in `FieldName` I chose from the list: `Person_Dog_Relation.name` but it didn't work. All cells in column `pet_id` are empty.

How I can actually fill the cells for column `pet_id` with dog `name`?

Comment: please post what have you tried so far, it will help us to help you...

Comment: As I said I tried to fill FieldName attribute of column with: <RelationName>.<FieldName> but it didnt work. Iam asking if its possible because when I open combobox of available values for FieldName I can see that I can choose there a relation and then a field from this relation.

Answer (score 0):

With reference from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235821/display-values-from-relation-table-in-xtragrid#comment18056338_13235821), you don't need to assign field name from relation.

Instead add a [LookUpEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsLookUpEdittopic) to the column holding **Pet_id**.

Assign lookupedit datasource from pet table table and set **Pet_id** as `ValueMember` and **Pet_Name** as `DisplayMember`

Comment: Hmm your solution seem not to work :(
In FieldName I have Pet_id in ColumnEditor I have Lookupedit where datasoruce is a new databindingSource of PetTable, there in ValueMember I Have Pet_id and DisplayMember: Pet_name. Even on designer column for each row is empty...
DataSource for lookupedit and grid are ofcourse different.